# How to handle HTML5 Canvas consuming pinch-to-zoom on tablet?

Tags: html, canvas, touch, tablet

I have been doing a fair bit of research and reading into the following scenario:

Scenario:

- User touches the screen in such a way as to pinch-to-zoom in on the canvas element.
- Canvas element now takes up 100% of the width and height of the viewport after zooming.
- User is now unable to unzoom or remove themselves from this state without hitting the back button. Pinch-to-zoom is consumed by the canvas.

The design specifications for our web application necessitate the ability to pinch-to-zoom on the page housing the canvas. As such, [the suggested best practice of disabling user-scalability on the tablet](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/#toc-foo) is not applicable to my scenario.

- Is it conceptually possible to bubble the multi-touch "pinch-to-zoom" event up from the canvas element to the browser/tablet?
- Are there other, less-obvious solutions I should consider other than:

  - Invisible div overlay on the canvas. Disable all user-interactivity, but support pinch-to-zoom.
  - Somehow provide a way of unzooming that doesn't involve a gesture so that the user can escape from the scenario outlined above.